# Can other applications monitor/access my apps internal memory after rooting

Tags: android, root

I want to build a security related application. I would be storing some important information (files) in my Applications private memory.

1. Can a FileObserving application detect/access changes to my internal app section in case device is rooted?
   I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8044178/340068) .In the question itself it seems that even after rooting , other applications wont be able to access my internal app data unless the user changes the access permissions on those files.
2. Can an application change file permissions of my app when rooted and access those files?

I can store the files in encrypted format but i just want to know how easy is to access my apps data after phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Alok. Private data of other apps can be seen on rooted phones.